# How can I format a date within BIRT's Expression Builder

Tags: date, format, report, birt

I have a BIRT report that includes a data cell and one dataSetRow is a date (expirydate) in YYYY-MM-DD format.  I need it to be in DD-MM-YY format, can I do this within BIRT's expression builder?

```
... + dataSetRow["expirydate"] + ")"
```

I can't just format the whole cell, as it contains a variety of information.

I'm using BIRT Report Designer, Version: 2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

Got round this in the end by placing `df = newjava.text.SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");`
at the top of the expression and then prefixing the relevant data set with "df.format": `df.format(dataSetRow["expirydate"])`

Solution found [here](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/781976/) (first reply post).